# Weird behaviour when running a program with make test and calling it directly ./prog

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, ubuntu-12.04

I'm a real C++ noob, so bear with me.

I have a simple program. When I compile it with `g++ -Wall prog.cpp -o prog` and then run it with `./prog` it just segfaults.

After some tinkering I wrote a makefile (see below). If I run `make test`, the program compiles and runs fine. If I run it with `./prog`, it segfaults. (The exact error message is `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`)

**Can anyone explain why?**

Here is the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));

    //int i, j, k, i2, j2, k2;
    int N = 1000;

    double mul1[N][N];
    double mul2[N][N];
    double res[N][N];

    printf("N: %d\n", N);

    for(int x=0; x<N; x++) {
        for(int y=0; y<N; y++) {
            mul1[x][y] = rand() % 100;
            mul2[x][y] = rand() % 100;
            res[x][y] = 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the makefile:

```
all: prog

prog: prog.cpp
    $(CXX) -Wall -g -o $@ prog.cpp

test: prog
    ./prog

clean: 
    rm -f prog
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First:

```
int N = 1000;

double mul1[N][N];
double mul2[N][N];
double res[N][N];
```

You have a stack overflow.

Assuming `double` is `8` bytes on your platform, your 3 arrays are more than 20 MB (`3 * 8 * 1000 * 1000`) in size. For example on my Linux machine the stack size allocated for every process is 8192 kB.

Second:

Regarding why it does not work on the shell but it works in the Makefile context you can try this:

Change `N` to `10` (so it does no longer segfault) and add this function call at the beginning of your program:

```
 system("ulimit -s");  // system is in stdlib.h
```

You'll see that the stack size is different in the shell (for example the printed value of `system` is `8192`) than in the Makefile context (for example the printed value of `system` is `unlimited`).

Comment: Please bear with me: My machine has 2GB RAM, how is this a problem? And why does it work with `make test`? Thanks!

Comment: You have 2GB of *physical* memory. The stack overflow issue has to do with virtual memory and address space. It has nothing whatsoever to do with use of physical memory.

Comment: @Wukerplank this is not a question of RAM you have but of how much the OS allocates for each process. In Linux use `ulimit -s` to know how much.

Comment: Ok, got it. My stack size is 8192 kB as well. Still the `make test` thing that bugs me...

Comment: @Wukerplank are you sure the program is executed? Add a `printf` before the `return 0;` statement to ensure.

Comment: @ouah Thanks for the update on the Makefile context! Consider my mind blown.